# "Sudden/short shiver" in English

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, sentence-usage

How do we say this in English when our body suddenly shakes for a moment due to change in temperature?
Sometimes, when we go to a place at higher temperature than that of where we were before, we experience a shiver for roughly 2 seconds. I don't know how we say that in English.

Comment: My body was "tingling" with the cold?

Comment: @MamtaD Tingling is a different sensation. It is the feeling as if a lot of small sharp points are pushing into a part of our body. It's not what I asked, anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can say "I *shuddered* with the sudden blast of icy wind."

Answer (score 1):

If the temperature suddenly dropped, you could say you felt a *chill*.